# No funciona la función Suma multiplicando y sumando múltiples filas

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Estoy tratando de multiplicar los campos cantidad y valor unitario del producto perteneciente al detalle de la factura de compra. Pero me he encontrado con que, solo suma solo las cantidades y valores unitarios de una única factura, he probado usando, criterios, agruparlos, entre otros, pero solo consigo que se sume solo los de una sola factura.

Estoy usando la función de suma que permite usar access de la siguiente forma.

```
Resultado: ([Detalle_Compra]![Cant_Compra]*[Detalle_Compra]![Valor_Compra])
```

#### SQL

```
SELECT Sum([Detalle_Compra] ! [Cant_Compra] * [Detalle_Compra] ! [Valor_Compra]) AS Resultado
FROM (
    Proveedores INNER JOIN (
        Compras INNER JOIN Detalle_Compra ON Compras.Codigo_Compra = Detalle_Compra.Cod_Compra
        ) ON Proveedores.Id_Proveedor = Compras.Id_Proveedor
    )
INNER JOIN T_Abonos_Compras ON Compras.Codigo_Compra = T_Abonos_Compras.Num_Fact_Compra;
```

Usando esta forma, solo arroja el resultado de Suma de una única factura, y pienso que debería arrojar la suma de todo lo que hay en el detalle de la factura de compra sin excepción, ya que no estoy usando criterios, en ese momento, luego, si coloco criterios, en este caso un proveedor que se que tiene dos facturas tipo crédito, que es lo que necesito, aparece el mismo resultado, de la misma factura.

Los resultado del estado de la factura y el proveedor cuales arroja resultado son los siguientes

**Estado_Factura** = "Credito"
**Nit_Proveedor** = "224933580-5"

Debería sumar y arrojar lo siguiente:

250.000 + 24.696.000 = 24.946.000

Pero si cambio el proveedor por otro, en este caso por el siguiente **"1065661179-2"**, el cual también tiene una factura a crédito, y debería aparecer, no aparece nada.

[image: uno]
[image: dos]
[image: tres]

Comment: ¿El problema ocurre en las tres versiones?

Comment: No pongo asi, para llamar la atencion de varias personas que sepan de access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente consulta la considero correcta, y debería sumarte todas las cantidades*Valor de todas las compras

```
SELECT Sum(D.Cant_Compra * D.Valor_Compra) AS Resultado 
FROM (Compras C INNER JOIN Detalle_Compra D ON C.Codigo_Compra = D.Cod_Compra)
INNER JOIN Proveedores P ON P.Id_Proveedor = C.Id_Proveedor
```

Esa consulta es la raíz de la consulta, y no usa la tabla [T_Abonos_Compras].
Dado que la consulta de arriba estoy convencido que es correcta, imagino que el problema está en el JOIN que tienes con esa tabla de abonos.

Toda compra no tiene porque tener un abono, pero haciendo este INNER JOIN haces que solo se vean las compras que hayan tenido un abono
Si no tienen abono, no te aparecerá la COMPRA.
Si quieres que te aparezcan las compras, tendrás que usar un LEFT JOIN.

Otro detalle a tener en cuenta es verificar que no puedan haber 2 abonos de una misma factura, ya que eso duplicaría la informaciòn. 
Esto depende por completo de la lógica que hayas usado para la estructura de tu base de datos.
Te pongo un ejemplo de 1 compra con 2 abonos:

```
Compra1 --> 10unidades * 10€ = 100€ --> Abono1 20€
Compra1 --> 10unidades * 10€ = 100€ --> Abono2 40€
```

El JOIN genera dos líneas, y el Sum() que usas en la consulta sumaría los 100€ de cada una de las líneas

```
Resultado: 100€ + 100€ = 200€ --> Resultado Abono: 60€
```

Por otra parte, no estoy seguro porque haces JOIN con la tabla de ABONOS, si en la consulta no usas ningún campo de esa campo para ningún cálculo. 
Aunque imagino que la finalidad era también tener en cuenta el valor del abono

Por ello, mis consejos son:

1) No usar la tabla de ABONOS si no piensas utilizar el valor del abono en ningún cálculo

```
SELECT Sum(D.Cant_Compra * D.Valor_Compra) AS Resultado
FROM ((Compras C INNER JOIN Detalle_Compra D ON C.Codigo_Compra = D.Cod_Compra)
INNER JOIN Proveedores P ON P.Id_Proveedor = C.Id_Proveedor)
```

2) Si vas a tener en cuenta el abono, utiliza LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT Sum(D.Cant_Compra * D.Valor_Compra - A.Valor_Abono_Compra) AS Resultado
FROM ((Compras C INNER JOIN Detalle_Compra D ON C.Codigo_Compra = D.Cod_Compra)
INNER JOIN Proveedores P ON P.Id_Proveedor = C.Id_Proveedor)
LEFT JOIN T_Abonos_Compras A ON C.Codigo_Compra = A.Num_Fact_Compra
```

3) Pero si una factura puede tener varios abonos, tendrás que unificar los abonos antes de poder hacer un JOIN.
Este ejemplo unifica los Abonos antes de aplicar el JOIN, pero dependiendo del volumen la consulta podría ir muy lenta

```
SELECT Sum(D.Cant_Compra * D.Valor_Compra - A.Total_Valor_Abono_Compra) AS Resultado
FROM ((Compras C INNER JOIN Detalle_Compra D ON C.Codigo_Compra = D.Cod_Compra)
INNER JOIN Proveedores P ON P.Id_Proveedor = C.Id_Proveedor)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Num_Fact_Compra, Sum(Valor_Abono_Compra) as Total_Valor_Abono_Compra
    FROM T_Abonos_Compras GROUP BY Num_Fact_Compra)A 
ON C.Codigo_Compra = A.Num_Fact_Compra
```

*NOTAS: Puede que las consultas den algún error porque no las he verificado en una consulta real sql, aunque seguramente sean pequeños detalles de sintaxis*

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me dice que hay un error en el `INNER` no se por que, de igual forma estoy usando access, y con la ayuda del creador de consultas, o obtuve de esta forma. [enlace consulta](https://pastebin.com/4Z0e5zdT)

Comment: Ciertamente había un error muy visible (me sobraba un INNER JOIN en un sitio que no le tocaba). He editado la respuesta, aunque podría seguir teniendo algún error porque no lo he pasado por el SQL.

Comment: El creador de consultas siempre crea las uniones usando INNER JOIN por defecto. No obstante, puedes crear LEFT JOIN's si pulsas el botón derecho sobre la relación. De esa forma te saldrá una opción que debe poner algo así: "Incluir todos los resultados de la tabla [Compras]". Con ello, te aseguras que, aunque no haya abonos, que siempre te aparezcan las compras. Pero recuerda, lo que pone realmente no lo se, pero debe ser algo así. Aun así, no hay nada mejor que crear las consultas a pelo (siempre y cuando sepas usar consutlas SQL)

Comment: De igual forma gracias.